# Use Multiple FormBuilder for form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From the official guide I see that we can use another FormBuilder in form for:

```
<%= form_for @person, builder: LabellingFormBuilder do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
<% end %>
```

However how I can use multiple forms builders from different gems together? (e.g. SimpleForm and Bootstrap form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do this.

Form related gems usually is a class extending `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder`. If there are two of these, we can't make a class extending these classes to gain the functionality of both.

Unless in the future, Rails adds an `ApplicationFormBuilder` and encourage gem authors to provide modules to prepend to it.

Answer (score 0):

> You can also build forms using a customized FormBuilder class.
>   Subclass FormBuilder and override or define some more helpers, then
>   use your custom builder. For example, let's say you made a helper to
>   automatically add labels to form inputs.

It means your form builder `LabellingFormBuilder` need to be inherited from class `FormBuilder` and override or define some more helpers.
List of methods, you can find at [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html).

---

To use `SimpleForm`, you need to use `simple_form_for` instead of `form_for`:

```
<%= simple_form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
<% end %>
```

Simple Form can be easily integrated to the `Bootstrap`. To do that you have to use the bootstrap option in the install generator, like this:

`rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap`